# How did "as" amass all its confusing "broad and vague meanings"?

Tags: etymology

From Bahrych, Merino. *Legal Writing and Analysis in a Nutshell 5th edition* ([2017](https://subscription.westacademic.com/Book/Detail/25181)). 343:

> **as**. Do not use the conjunction *as* when you mean “since,” “because,” “when,” or “while.” Its broad and vague meanings can create confusion. For example, *As a potential work stoppage threatened to block the opening of school, the arbitrators revised the wording of the contract*. Does as mean “when,” “because,” or “while”?

https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=as doesn't answer my question. Incontrovertibly,

> “since,” “because,” “when,” or “while”

are NOT completely synonymous. For example "since" can mean "because", but "because" can't mean "since".

**More Examples.** [General Electric is the only company that has retained its place on the DJIA under its original name since <s>because</s> the index's inception.](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/100214/who-were-original-dow-jones-industrial-average-djia-companies.asp)  When <s>While</s> did you last get your teeth cleaned?

Comment: As did many English words.

Comment: As likely as not.

Comment: I've always considered _as_ a distant and feckless cousin of _is_. Wherever it gets into an idiom (which is normally where you find it), it assumes some kind of linking sense that's not all that different from _be_ (though often there is no convenient chunk of _be_ to use instead).

Answer (score -2):

OED:

As adv. & conj.

> **Origin:** A variant or alteration of another lexical item. Etymon: also adv.
>
> **Etymology:** Originally the same word as **also** adv., now distinguished in form in the senses below.
>
> The current form of the headword is the result of the progressive phonetic reduction of Old English eall swa , which originated as an intensification of so adv. and conj. (see also adv. and compare Germanic parallels cited at that entry). This intensive formation was used in Old English in all of the main historical senses of so adv. and conj., appearing in correlative constructions expressing comparison of equivalence, most commonly as an antecedent adverb in a main clause (e.g. eallswa beorht swa gold : compare sense A.) but also as a relative conjunction in the subordinate clause (e.g. eallswa beorht eallswa gold : compare sense B.), and outside such constructions as a simple uncorrelated demonstrative adverb (see Old English examples at also adv.).

Comment: a header "OED:" does unfortunately not suffice to satisfy copyright law requirements. And a simple copy-paste not really answer the question (which might be a tad too broad answer in one sitting). We don't see definitions A or B implied in the text, nor anything about *so*, which is a whole paradigmatic family of related and unrelated meanings. Also, *swa* mentioned in the first line does not strictly belong to \*so but \*swe as far as I can tell. This distinction had always been confusing, as can be infered as wiktionary leaves a cautionary remark about Homeric *hos*, or at Latin *si*, or...

Comment: ... the fact that *all* cannot be easily derived from \*h2el- without confronting the flipside of this question, how could \*h2el- develop so many diverse meanings such as seen in *old*, and *aliance* (hint: it couldn't). Last but not least, how is this to be distinguished from *ea* (IIRC) that is possibly the first element in *ever*.